# Does JavaScript codes in HTML page uses client machine's power or server's machine power?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring, performance

I'm writing a website in String-framework and there are lots of codes for replacing specific characters in a String. and since I found for-loop faster than the regular expression and I like my codes to run as fast as possible, I'm using for-loop to do this stuff.

but to make a good looking and safe web page, I need to use some JavaScript regular expression to replace any non-digit character of a `<input>` element inside of my web pages too.

and since I'm not a good javascript coder, I'm pretty sure my JS codes aren't so efficient. what I'm worried about is if these inefficient coded slows down the server.

Does the JavaScript codes inside an HTML page use the server's machine power for calculations? or client's machines who are visiting the webpage?

I know writing efficient JavaScript codes is a must, but I'm just learning it

Thanks in advance.

Comment: by the way you can use <input type="number"> to only allow number in that input tag

Comment: "_Does the JavaScript codes inside an HTML page use the server's machine power_" No, it doesn't. All the JS of a HTML page happens inside the client's browser only. Before worrying too much of the performance, please read [this](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/).

Comment: @Andam yes, but it's a real-time conversion, and I want the calculations to be done by the time the user writes something, that's why I'm using javascript.
thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it uses clients computer resources in your case. But just to be noted you can also run on server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I know JavaScript can be used for backend, but I clearly said "JavaScript codes inside of HTML page".

Comment: I have updated the answer and the second part is was not for you. I know you said HTML. I wrote it for other people looking at your question and the answers.